# Compare Oracle Table with legacy data that has spaces

Tags: database, oracle, comparison, database-comparison

I have a legacy goldengated table- Let us call it LEGACY_TABLE. This has 15 columns and 5K rows.
This LEGACY_TABLE has column values with a lot of trailing spaces.

My new table, let us call it NEW_TABLE. I created it manually by exporting data and creating sqls. removing spaces. Some Oracle HIGH dates.

Now I need to compare them to see if both tables are exactly the same BUT ignoring spaces.
What is the best way to compare the two tables? want to make sure they are exactly the same if I ignore the spaces.

Can this be done by SQL? Excel?

Comment: Hi , can you load both the tables in one DB and do a MINUS , like SELECT * FROM LEGACY_TABLE  MINUS SELECT * FROM NEW_LEGACY_TABLE and the other way around and see if you get any rows.

Comment: Both are in one Database. How do I deal with the spaces?

Comment: What does "Some Oracle HIGH dates" mean?

Comment: Are you *only* concerned about trailing spaces? You can use `rtrim()` if so, on all of the problem columns, in one or both tables. It's unclear if you mean *all* spaces. Knowing what "creating sqls. removing spaces" actually involved might be useful; as would knowing that "Some Oracle HIGH dates" means.

Comment: Yes, if spaces are ignored, data should be exactly same in both tables. Thats what I am trying to make sure. I created the NEW_TABLE by exporting LEGACY_TABLE data and manually removing spaces and creating insert queries and executing them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want

```
select trim(column1), trim(column2), ... trim(columnN)
  from legacy_table
minus
select column1, column2, ..., columnN
  from new_table
```

to show what is in the legacy table that is not in the new table and

```
select column1, column2, ..., columnN
  from new_table
minus
select trim(column1), trim(column2), ... trim(columnN)
  from legacy_table
```

to show the reverse.  You could do a single query with a `union all` to combine these two queries if you wanted to.